# Flutter TextField usando tema cupertino

Tags: flutter, dart

Preciso fazer uma barra de pesquisas que fique ao lado desse campo "Contatos":

```
child: CustomScrollView(
          //semanticChildCount: totalRows,
          slivers: <Widget>[
            CupertinoSliverNavigationBar(
              largeTitle: Text("Contatos"),

              //trailing: trailingButtons,
            ),
```

Basicamente um `TextField` com um ícone de lupa.

Andei lendo no site oficial do Flutter como eu poderia fazer isso mas não entendi muito bem.

Como eu poderia fazer uma barra de pesquisa igual a que citei acima?

Obs.: Sou novo em Flutter.

Comment: Eu particularmente não gosto dessa solução, por experiência pessoal os usuários vão querer clicar na lupa, então eu uso um Row com TextField e um FlatButtom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existe a propriedade "prefixIcon", abaixo a demonstração da utilização dela:

```
TextField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search)
    ),
)
```

Esse é o link da documentação dessa propriedade: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration/prefixIcon.html

[image: Exemplo de como ficaria com o icone]